# How to increase file uploading time for large file in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

there is any way in codeigniter for increase or decrease the file upload time . Can any body explain what will be happen after execution time is over.

for example - upload video of 200MB

```
$config['upload_path']          = 'upload/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'flv|mp4|3gp';
$config['max_size']             = 204800;          //200 MB
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

But you should ask your server firm. and you can check php.ini.

Find this line in the php.ini file “upload_max_filesize = 2M” and replace it with a higher value (e.g. “upload_max_filesize = 64M”)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 2M
```